# Property on an instance of MovieClip that the MovieClip class doesn't have

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I've inherited this Android application made in Flash.

The code should be working fine, but I can't get it to run.

It crashes with a term undefined error when trying to set a property called pageTitle:

```
foo.pageTitle.text = "Hello!"
```

So when I looked up foo, it's coming from the flash movie, and it's a MovieClip.

MovieClip doesn't have a pageTitle property which I presume is why it's crashing.

I can see the text "Hello!" overlaid over that MovieClip when I run the compiled app, so it's working somehow if I could only compile it.

Should something be extending or wrapping MovieClip somewhere but I don't have it? Could I have a different version of some SDK? I have no idea. I have lots of coding experience in various languages on various platforms but very little Flash experience.

Answer (score 1):

MovieClip is a dynamic class, which means that properties can be added a runtime. I assume you are getting a null reference error because the object pageTitle is refering to is not set or initialized.

You can do a simple check to see if it references a valid object:

```
if (foo.pageTitle) {
  foo.pageTitle.text = "Hello!"
}
```

If it is not referenced, there might be an issue with the movieclip; the pageTitle might simply not be there or the movieclip might not be fully intialized